# Validation in XText project

Tags: validation, xtext, emf, xtend

I'm trying to validate if an object access to the same place where it is instanced, 
I have class Room and Door, room has doors and doors connect to rooms. 
Code that I'm using is:

```
@Check
def void sameRoom(Room room) {
    try {

        var acu=0;
        while (room.have!==null) {
            var doors=room.have;
            var nameRoom= room.name.toString() ;
            for (element : doors) {
                if (nameRoom.equals(element.access.name.toString())) {
                    acu++;
                }
            }
            if (acu>0) {
                error('Door can't address to the same place', 
                ProyectPackage.Literals.ROOM_HAVE,
                "Same place")
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.out.println(exception.message);
    }

}
```

When I execute this code, my cross references not appear and eclipse start to slow down

Comment: Did you try to debug the code. To me, it looks like an infinite loop since the condition `room.have!==null` will not change from one iteration to the next.

Comment: You are right I was testing the code and it start a infinite loop, it's possible to use for with size of elements instead of while ?

Comment: I would in general try to stick with for loops as they tend to protect you from issues like this. You can also simplify this quite a bit, try something like `for (door : room.have) {
                if (door.access.name.equals(room.name)) {
                    // error here
                }
            }`

Comment: You can also specify the door the error shows on by passing the third parameter to `error` as something like `room.have.indexof(door)`